# jQuery selector click function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply the following jQuery click function but for some reason I can't seem to get the selector right, i.e.:

```
$("ul.menu li a").click(function(){
   $("ul.menu li").find("a").removeAttr("id");
   $(this).attr("id" , "current" );
});
```

This is my HTML code I am trying to apply it to, i,e,:

```
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul class="menu noaccordion">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="current" class="topm">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="topm">About Us</a>
                </li>
```

My aim is to try and set the current menu selected using the id=current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
$("ul.menu li a").click(function(){
   $(".topm").attr('id', '');
   $(this).attr("id" , "current" );
});
```

Comment: @Kaaviar - I used Jacob's code but it didn't seem to work for my case, unsure if it's a DOM thing but appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't remove the ID of the element.  The ID attribute is designed to represent a single element in the DOM. You should really apply this with a class instead:

```
$("ul.menu li a").removeClass("currentMenu");
$(this).addClass("currentMenu");
```

So in your example:-

```
$("ul.menu li a").click(function() {
  $("ul.menu li a").removeClass("currentMenu");
  $(this).addClass("currentMenu");
});
```

You don't need to use each, as the removeClass action will be applied to each jquery result from the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a class name that indicates that a menu is selected instead of id:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="topm selected">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="topm">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then your click function might look like this:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    $('ul a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it going from my original code plus the addition of a `.find("a")` on the last line, which has solved my problem, i.e.

```
    $("#sidebar ul.menu li").click(function() {
       $("ul.menu li").find("a").removeAttr("id");
       $(this).find("a").attr("id" , "current" );
    });
```